# For loop in forms

Tags: c#

I want my form to display 1,2,3,4,5
but all it does is replace the text again and again.

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++)
{
    richTextBox1.Text = Convert.ToString(i);
}
```

I know it's because of the .Text that it always overrides itself. But how can i leave them in the form so it will display:

```
1
2
3
4
5
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that in your loop, you're completely replacing the text with each iteration. So the text is left with whatever the last value of `i` was.

Try putting adding to the current text (with `+=`) and putting a new line (`Environment.NewLine` or `"\n"`) between each number:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++)
{
    richTextBox1.Text += Environment.NewLine + Convert.ToString(i);
}
```

Or alternatively, a little Linq can make your life a lot easier:

```
richTextBox1.Text = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, Enumerable.Range(1, 5));
```

Comment: you probably should use `Environment.NewLine` as a separator. OP had each number on separate line in the answer.

Comment: @IlyaIvanov Good catch, thanks for updating the question to highlight OP's original intent.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++)
{
    richTextBox1.Text += Convert.ToString(i) + Environment.NewLine;
}
```

Edit:

Just noticed that you want to print one number per line.  `\n` is the NewLine character and will give you a carriage return on the end of the line.

[Environment.NewLine](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.newline%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is also a good choice, because it will give you the newline character based on the environment the app is running in.

Answer (score 0):

append text, don't just assign it.

```
richTextBox1.Text += Convert.ToString(i);
```

this is equivelant of

```
richTextBox1.Text = richTextBox1.Text + Convert.ToString(i);
```

Answer (score 0):

This will also do:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++)
{
    richTextBox1.AppendText(i + Environment.NewLine);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
richTextBox1.AppendText(i.ToString()+Environment.NewLine);
```